# EverNote API findNotesMetadata does not return every note with the filter created time

Tags: php, api, evernote

Recently I noticed a problem with the Evernote API.

When I use the API method "findNotesMetadata" (https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/searching_notes.php) with as filter:

```
/**
* Retrieving notes from today to 7 days ago.
*/

//
$timestamp = strtotime ( '-7 day' , $timestamp);

//set filter
$filter = new NoteFilter();
$filter->words = 'created:' . date('Ymd', $timestamp);

//order
$filter->order = NoteSortOrder::CREATED;

//set spec
$spec = new NotesMetadataResultSpec();
$spec->includeTitle = true;
$spec->includeContentLength = false;
$spec->includeCreated = true;
$spec->includeUpdated = true;
$spec->includeDeleted = true;
$spec->includeUpdateSequenceNum = false;
$spec->includeNotebookGuid = true;
$spec->includeTagGuids = true;
$spec->includeAttributes = false;
$spec->includeLargestResourceMime = false;
$spec->includeLargestResourceSize = false;

//get
$notes = $this->noteStore->findNotesMetadata($token, $filter, $from, $noteReturned, $spec);
```

Some notes created the day are not return.
When I make the same request without the filter, the notes do not appear are present(Their creation date and update date are today's date.).

II did a test by editing a note on the Evernote site(notes are currently entered and synchronized from the Evernote applicationrnot).
This action makes the note available about half an hour later on the API ...

I don't see where the problem is coming from. Evernetote API bug?

Comment: In fact, some notes are available in the API only X hours after their creation on the site(Evernote). When using the "created" filter.

How do I contact Evernote technical support?